# How can I use the data contract serializer for app settings?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer, application-settings

The data contract serializer has some advantages over the xml serializer, such as support for circular references and TimeSpan.  How can I use the data contract serializer for my app settings?

Comment: Why? `ConfigurationManager` already gives you access to `AppSettings`.

Comment: @Oded I'm serializing an array of my own class, which has a TimeSpan member.

Comment: OK. So why not create a custom `ConfigurationSection` and use that? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have strongly typed data in your `.config` file, you should write your own configuration section.

This is not difficult - you simply have to inherit from `ConfigurationSection`, add your types to serialize and override a few methods, as described in [How to: Create Custom Configuration Sections Using ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I wanted to work with .settings file, but iiuc custom configuration sections are separate, right?

Comment: @BrunoMartinez - Correct. They go into the `.config` file.